# IOS screen orientation phonegap

Tags: ios, angularjs, cordova, phonegap-plugins, screen-orientation

I have a mobile application which can use portrait or landscape mode. But on one page, I would like to force the view on landscape mode.
For that I use a Phonegap plugin called "cordova-plugin-screen-orientation". I tried with a lot off differents versions of this plugin. Once in a while I have issue on the screenshot below, but only on IOS. It works fine on Android.

[Show printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jwHr.png)

- Phonegap version : 6.0.3
- Cordave version : 4.2.0
- Plugin version : 1.4.2

Thanks for your help !

Best regards

Comment: Not usre how to help, can you show your code for the orientation?

Answer (score 0):

This should be in your config.xml

```
 <preference name="Orientation" value="portrait" />
```

Answer (score 0):

[Cordova plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation) to set/lock the screen orientation in a common way for iOS and Android.The plugin adds the following to the screen object (`window.screen`):

```
// lock the device orientation
.lockOrientation('portrait')

// unlock the orientation
.unlockOrientation()

// current orientation
.orientation
// set to either landscape
screen.lockOrientation('landscape');

// allow user rotate
screen.unlockOrientation();

// access current orientation
console.log('Orientation is ' + screen.orientation);
```

Both android and iOS will fire the orientationchange event on the window object. For this version of the plugin use the window object if you require notification.